# How to convert python 3.X scripts into exe files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

I've a simple python script that I want to see it as an exe file so I can run it in any computer.

My friend told me about py2exe. But, when I searched it, I found that it's limited to  python 2.X . I wrote my script in 3.X python (3.4 , the last realese till the moment).

I wonder, How can I convert 3.x python scripts into excutable exe files?

Any sugesstions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Answer (score 3):

you can try  [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net)!

This module supports python3.x well.

Comment: Is this a module in python like random or math? (I', new to programming so excuse me if I ask dull questions)

Comment: @MathsLover no, it is not a built-in module, you have to install it yourself by run `pip install cx_freeze` in your commandline.

Comment: I've download the file from the site. I wrote the command you typed in the interpreter, it gives error. Could you provide me with the steps please?

Comment: @MathsLover specific your python version and system platform in your question. DO NOT execute the command in python, but in your system cmd/terminal instead.

Comment: I excuted it in the cmd and gave me "syntaxerror: invalid syntax".

Comment: @MathsLover ╮(╯_╰)╭...that's amazing! `syntaxerror: invalid syntax `shows with python repr not your cmd. Exit python and execute the command.

Comment: I exited python. I wrote it in cmd and it still gives me the same error syntax message. if you don't believe it, I can show you a print screen If you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60132/discussion-between-paleneutron-and-maths-lover).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the "pyinstaller" module. The steps below will tell you how to install and use it:

Get the command prompt up and ready

1. Install the pyinstaller module (write this in the command prompt):

   pip install pyinstaller
2. Change the directory to the folder that has the Python script(write in cmd too):

   cd The\directory\of\your\code
3. Convert the file(still in the cmd)

   pyinstaller --onefile nameOfYourScript.py

The EXE file will be in the dist folder

**PLEASE NOTE:** You must have Python added to path otherwise this won't work.