# creating a exe file using python 3.6 and cx_freeze5.0.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, exe, cx-freeze

I'm having an issue opening the `.exe` file that I created using `cx_freeze` 5.0.1 and python 3.6. (Windows 10   64 bit)

I'm attaching the error I received and setup.py which I used to create the file.

The issue is coming from tkinter not being recognized

I've been looking for hours for a solution online but I'm pretty clueless

[image: Error when I try to open the exe file]

```
import sys,os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable



os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6'



setup(
    name = "Name of app",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Any Description you like",
    executables = [Executable("App.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best method of converting .py to .exe for Python 3.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/best-method-of-converting-py-to-exe-for-python-3-6)