# How do compile a .py file into a .exe without any downloads

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, executable

I wrote a simple Python script which I want to give my friends. I have done hours of research without a result. I even tried using `cx_freeze` (which royal slowed down my computer and almost broke my computer) and it made an `.exe` that didn't even work.

After that I don't want to download anything else. Please help?

I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best method of converting .py to .exe for Python 3.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/best-method-of-converting-py-to-exe-for-python-3-6)

Answer (score 0):

Use either PyInstaller (http://www.pyinstaller.org/), or Py2Exe (http://www.py2exe.org/). I'm sure there are other alternatives out there, but from experience, PyInstaller is a really good one.

By the way, you cannot natively compile a python code into exe. What those software will do is basically freeze the minimalist Python runtime environment with your scripts to make them run as a stand-alone software.

Answer (score 0):

You don't, most solid option is py2exe.

You can check it here: http://www.py2exe.org

P.S.: Using it can be a little tricky for beginners, but don't give up.