# Python exe file doesnt work

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am using python 3.6 on Windows. I downloaded "cx_Freeze-4.3.3.win-amd64-py3.3" to make my "python script " to an exe file.
I managed to get an exe file under build folder but it doesn't work.

this is my code

```
#script file which I named scriptbutton.py.txt
print("hello")
```

And this is the code I am using for set-up script.(scriptsetup.py.txt)

```
import os.path
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\LOCAL_TO_PYTHON\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\LOCAL_TO_PYTHON\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tk8.6" 

setup (name= 'scripting', version='3.1', description='make exe file', 
       executables= [Executable ("scriptbutton.py.txt", base="Win32GUI")])
```

this is the error message, when I double clicked on exe file.

[image: this is the error message, when I double clicked on exe file.]

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Well the error speaks for itself: you did not included the `scriptbutton` module.

Comment: how should i include the scriptbutton module ? it is the script i typed.

Comment: did you included an empty `__init__.py` file in the directory? Otherwise it is not a module

Comment: yes I have added the ' __init.py__ ' file in the "cx_Freeze\initscripts" directory. But it didnt work. Is it the correct place to put the file? should i put somewhere else? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: what about the `scriptbutton` directory?

Comment: I received the same error message.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I simply add a  **___init___.py** file in the directory. I dont know if I should write a code. I am a bit stranger to the subject. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: i solved it. one part of the problem was the txt extension of the file. I made them only py files. and use this setup code for python 3.6.  [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/best-method-of-converting-py-to-exe-for-python-3-6

Comment: ah, glad you solved it :).