# cx_freeze ImportError: No module named 'idna'

Tags: cx-freeze, python-3.6

I'm using python 3.6
Trying to make and exe from my .py file. but when I run python setup.py build
it give me an error

raise ImportError("No module named %r" % name)
ImportError: No module named 'idna'

My setup file is like this
[setup file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3e4ErQeXruDSmFYV2poSGhJY1k/view)

Answer (score 0):

Save:

```
# thanks to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSoOwSqTSrs
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name='KutsalAklinNerde?',
    version='0.1',              #Further information about its version
    description='Parse stuff',  #It's description
    executables= [Executable("Example.py")])
```

as ***setup.py*** in the same directory of your ***Example.py*** (the .py you want to convert to .exe)

And then run ***>python setup.py build*** in that directory with command prompt.