# How to generate standalone exe file from python 3.6 scripts

Tags: python-3.6

How to convert .py file into standalone exe file for python3.6, please explain with examples

Please explain it with some examples to make setup.py file, so that I can execute any text file called in python script and save the output in csv file by calling the csv file.

Comment: Your response will be a great help for me. Thanks

Comment: My OS configuration is Windows 7, 64bit

Comment: I need to execute the python script on windows command prompt without installing python software (IDE) or modules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best method of converting .py to .exe for Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/best-method-of-converting-py-to-exe-for-python-3-6)

Comment: Yeah, I have installed pyinstaller and cx_Freeze already, but I am not able to understand the 3-6 steps given in Best method of converting .py to .exe for Python 3.6?  page, please give me some exapmples to make setup file

Comment: Did you not see the link in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/best-method-of-converting-py-to-exe-for-python-3-6 "4. On the setup.py, code >>this<< and save it." which contains the content of the setup.py?

Comment: Thanks to all, I already solved the issue by myself.