# Converting Python program with command line argument into executable using PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I would like to convert a python code with command line argument into windows executable using pyInstaller. I run my python program as follows

```
python myPython 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i wonder that you don't get articles related to to this in your Google search.

First Install pyinstaller by running this command

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

For Additional Help
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Open command prompt, Now navigate to the directory in which your python file (using the cd command ) is located then enter the code

pyinstaller --onefile .py

This will create a standalone executable file (That i expect you are asking). Below is the link to a stackoverflow question you missed to read. Edit : in the same directory a folder name dist will get created which have your single executable.

[How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)