# How do I convert a Python3 file i to .exe file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, executable

I've been coding on python for a while. Made quite a few games and applications. Now I want to share them but don't know how. I can't just ask my friends to download python on their computers.

Please Help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python

Answer (score 1):

[PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) is what you need.

> PyInstaller is a program that freezes (packages) Python programs into
>   stand-alone executables, under Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD,
>   Solaris and AIX. Its main advantages over similar tools are that
>   PyInstaller works with Python 2.7 and 3.4—3.7, it builds smaller
>   executables thanks to transparent compression, it is fully
>   multi-platform, and use the OS support to load the dynamic libraries,
>   thus ensuring full compatibility.

EDIT: Added quickstart guide: Copied from the `quickstart` of `PyInstaller`:

Install `PyInstaller` from `PyPI`:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Go to your program’s directory and run:

```
pyinstaller yourprogram.py
```

This will generate the bundle in a subdirectory called `dist`.

For a more detailed walkthrough, see the [manual](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: This is embarrassing, but could u please tell me how exactly do I use pyinstaller?

Comment: I've made an edit. For short, in the link I provided you, there is a quickstart. I don't want to include it in my answer since it is unnecessary long.

Comment: Thanks for the help... Happy Coding!

Comment: False alarm... It converted to .pyc file. How do I fix that?

Comment: And there wasn't any dist folder either

Comment: Is there any error occur during your run? Post it here so we can help you.

Comment: It worked! Thank u!