# Created executable application does not work

Tags: python

For information, my PC is equipped with windows 10 64 bits, and I use python 3.6

I finished my `script python (cev.py), and I turned it into an executable application by this command:

```
python setup.py buld
```

and I also tried this command:

```
python setup.py bdist_msi
```

1. For the first case, I have a build folder that was created and that contains my executable application.
2. For the second case, I have two folders `build`, and `dist`.

In both the cases, when I run my executable application created, it does not work.

File `setup.py`:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win64":
    base = "Win64GUI"

setup(  name = "cev",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My CEV application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("cev.py", base=base)])
```

Comment: Can you share your directory structure ?

Comment: This can be a duplicate for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python

Comment: my application.exe is created in a folder "build" but not executable ; and the directory strucure is like this picture :

https://zupimages.net/up/18/51/u54c.jpg