# How to package all the required libraries with the python program so that it can run in all systems?

Tags: python, import, module, automation, package

I just made a `tkinter` widget on python. I wish to pass it to my friend who has python but not `tkinter` library.

He is right now receiving a `module not found error`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that your terminal is in the current directory where the project is located.
You have to run `pip freeze` on terminal to list the libraries installed and save the output on `requirements.txt`. On unix based OSes, you can run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, making the libraries saved on requirements.txt automaticallly. To install those libraries coming from the `requirements.txt` you can run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Much better if you have a background in using Virtual Environments.