# How do I compile a pytorch script into an exe file with small size?

Tags: python, pytorch, pyinstaller

I have a semantic segmentation model using `PyTorch`. In order to participate in a competition, I am compiling the `test.py` to an exe file with `PyInstaller` and `UPX`. Although the resulting executable file runs correctly, its size is nearly **800MB**. How do I make it smaller?

This is my test.py:

```
from torch import nn
from torch.autograd import Variable as V
from torch import Tensor
from torch import cuda
from torch import load

import cv2
import os
import numpy as np


from time import time

from networks.unet import Unet
# from networks.dunet import Dunet
# from networks.dinknet import LinkNet34, DinkNet34, DinkNet50, DinkNet101, DinkNet34_less_pool
# from networks.dinkbranch import DinkBranch50, DinkBranch34

BATCHSIZE_PER_CARD = 2

class TTAFrame():
    def __init__(self, net):
        self.net = net().cuda()
        self.net = nn.DataParallel(self.net, device_ids=range(cuda.device_count()))

    def test_one_img_from_path(self, path, evalmode = True):
        if evalmode:
            self.net.eval()
        batchsize = cuda.device_count() * BATCHSIZE_PER_CARD
        if batchsize >= 8:
            return self.test_one_img_from_path_1(path)
        elif batchsize >= 4:
            return self.test_one_img_from_path_2(path)
        elif batchsize >= 2:
            return self.test_one_img_from_path_4(path)

    def test_one_img_from_path_8(self, path):
        img = cv2.imread(path)#.transpose(2,0,1)[None]
        img90 = np.array(np.rot90(img))
        img1 = np.concatenate([img[None],img90[None]])
        img2 = np.array(img1)[:,::-1]
        img3 = np.array(img1)[:,:,::-1]
        img4 = np.array(img2)[:,:,::-1]

        img1 = img1.transpose(0,3,1,2)
        img2 = img2.transpose(0,3,1,2)
        img3 = img3.transpose(0,3,1,2)
        img4 = img4.transpose(0,3,1,2)

        img1 = V(Tensor(np.array(img1, np.float32)/255.0 * 3.2 -1.6).cuda())
        img2 = V(Tensor(np.array(img2, np.float32)/255.0 * 3.2 -1.6).cuda())
        img3 = V(Tensor(np.array(img3, np.float32)/255.0 * 3.2 -1.6).cuda())
        img4 = V(Tensor(np.array(img4, np.float32)/255.0 * 3.2 -1.6).cuda())

        maska = self.net.forward(img1).squeeze().cpu().data.numpy()
        maskb = self.net.forward(img2).squeeze().cpu().data.numpy()
        maskc = self.net.forward(img3).squeeze().cpu().data.numpy()
        maskd = self.net.forward(img4).squeeze().cpu().data.numpy()

        mask1 = maska + maskb[:,::-1] + maskc[:,:,::-1] + maskd[:,::-1,::-1]
        mask2 = mask1[0] + np.rot90(mask1[1])[::-1,::-1]

        return mask2

    def test_one_img_from_path_4(self, path):
        img = cv2.imread(path)#.transpose(2,0,1)[None]
        img90 = np.array(np.rot90(img))
        img1 = np.concatenate([img[None],img90[None]])
        img2 = np.array(img1)[:,::-1]
        img3 = np.array(img1)[:,:,::-1]
        img4 = np.array(img2)[:,:,::-1]

        img1 = img1.transpose(0,3,1,2)
        img2 = img2.transpose(0,3,1,2)
        img3 = img3.transpose(0,3,1,2)
        img4 = img4.transpose(0,3,1,2)

        img1 = V(Tensor(np.array(img1, np.float32)/255.0 * 3.2 -1.6).cuda())
        img2 = V(Tensor(np.array(img2, np.float32)/255.0 * 3.2 -1.6).cuda())
        img3 = V(Tensor(np.array(img3, np.float32)/255.0 * 3.2 -1.6).cuda())
        img4 = V(Tensor(np.array(img4, np.float32)/255.0 * 3.2 -1.6).cuda())

        maska = self.net.forward(img1).squeeze().cpu().data.numpy()
        maskb = self.net.forward(img2).squeeze().cpu().data.numpy()
        maskc = self.net.forward(img3).squeeze().cpu().data.numpy()
        maskd = self.net.forward(img4).squeeze().cpu().data.numpy()

        mask1 = maska + maskb[:,::-1] + maskc[:,:,::-1] + maskd[:,::-1,::-1]
        mask2 = mask1[0] + np.rot90(mask1[1])[::-1,::-1]

        return mask2

    def test_one_img_from_path_2(self, path):
        img = cv2.imread(path)#.transpose(2,0,1)[None]
        img90 = np.array(np.rot90(img))
        img1 = np.concatenate([img[None],img90[None]])
        img2 = np.array(img1)[:,::-1]
        img3 = np.concatenate([img1,img2])
        img4 = np.array(img3)[:,:,::-1]
        img5 = img3.transpose(0,3,1,2)
        img5 = np.array(img5, np.float32)/255.0 * 3.2 -1.6
        img5 = V(Tensor(img5).cuda())
        img6 = img4.transpose(0,3,1,2)
        img6 = np.array(img6, np.float32)/255.0 * 3.2 -1.6
        img6 = V(Tensor(img6).cuda())

        maska = self.net.forward(img5).squeeze().cpu().data.numpy()#.squeeze(1)
        maskb = self.net.forward(img6).squeeze().cpu().data.numpy()

        mask1 = maska + maskb[:,:,::-1]
        mask2 = mask1[:2] + mask1[2:,::-1]
        mask3 = mask2[0] + np.rot90(mask2[1])[::-1,::-1]

        return mask3

    def test_one_img_from_path_1(self, path):
        img = cv2.imread(path)#.transpose(2,0,1)[None]

        img90 = np.array(np.rot90(img))
        img1 = np.concatenate([img[None],img90[None]])
        img2 = np.array(img1)[:,::-1]
        img3 = np.concatenate([img1,img2])
        img4 = np.array(img3)[:,:,::-1]
        img5 = np.concatenate([img3,img4]).transpose(0,3,1,2)
        img5 = np.array(img5, np.float32)/255.0 * 3.2 -1.6
        img5 = V(Tensor(img5).cuda())

        mask = self.net.forward(img5).squeeze().cpu().data.numpy()#.squeeze(1)
        mask1 = mask[:4] + mask[4:,:,::-1]
        mask2 = mask1[:2] + mask1[2:,::-1]
        mask3 = mask2[0] + np.rot90(mask2[1])[::-1,::-1]

        return mask3

    def load(self, path):
        self.net.load_state_dict(load(path))

#source = 'dataset/test/'
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    arg1 = r'dataset/504/original'
else:
    arg1 = sys.argv[1]

# source = r'dataset/504/original'
source = arg1
source_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), source)

val = os.listdir(source_path)
solver = TTAFrame(Unet)
model_path = '/'
model_path = r'weights/log02_Unet.th'
solver.load(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), model_path))

tic = time()
target = r'submits/log02_baseline504'

target_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), target)
if os.path.exists(target_path):
    pass
else:
    os.makedirs(target_path)
for i,name in enumerate(val):
    if i%10 == 0:
        print(i/10, '    ','%.2f'%(time()-tic))
    mask = solver.test_one_img_from_path(os.path.join(source_path, name))
    mask[mask>4.0] = 255
    mask[mask<=4.0] = 0
    mask = np.concatenate([mask[:,:,None],mask[:,:,None],mask[:,:,None]],axis=2)
    cv2.imwrite(target_path+r'/'+name[:-7]+'mask.png', mask.astype(np.uint8))
```

This is the 'Unet' file:

```
from torch import autograd, cat
from torch import nn


class Unet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Unet, self).__init__()

        self.down1 = self.conv_stage(3, 8)
        self.down2 = self.conv_stage(8, 16)
        self.down3 = self.conv_stage(16, 32)
        self.down4 = self.conv_stage(32, 64)
        self.down5 = self.conv_stage(64, 128)
        self.down6 = self.conv_stage(128, 256)
        self.down7 = self.conv_stage(256, 512)

        self.center = self.conv_stage(512, 1024)
        #self.center_res = self.resblock(1024)

        self.up7 = self.conv_stage(1024, 512)
        self.up6 = self.conv_stage(512, 256)
        self.up5 = self.conv_stage(256, 128)
        self.up4 = self.conv_stage(128, 64)
        self.up3 = self.conv_stage(64, 32)
        self.up2 = self.conv_stage(32, 16)
        self.up1 = self.conv_stage(16, 8)

        self.trans7 = self.upsample(1024, 512)
        self.trans6 = self.upsample(512, 256)
        self.trans5 = self.upsample(256, 128)
        self.trans4 = self.upsample(128, 64)
        self.trans3 = self.upsample(64, 32)
        self.trans2 = self.upsample(32, 16)
        self.trans1 = self.upsample(16, 8)

        self.conv_last = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(8, 1, 3, 1, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        self.max_pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2)

        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d) or isinstance(m, nn.ConvTranspose2d):
                if m.bias is not None:
                    m.bias.data.zero_()

    def conv_stage(self, dim_in, dim_out, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=True, useBN=False):
        if useBN:
            return nn.Sequential(
              nn.Conv2d(dim_in, dim_out, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding, bias=bias),
              nn.BatchNorm2d(dim_out),
              #nn.LeakyReLU(0.1),
              nn.ReLU(),
              nn.Conv2d(dim_out, dim_out, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding, bias=bias),
              nn.BatchNorm2d(dim_out),
              #nn.LeakyReLU(0.1),
              nn.ReLU(),
            )
        else:
            return nn.Sequential(
              nn.Conv2d(dim_in, dim_out, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding, bias=bias),
              nn.ReLU(),
              nn.Conv2d(dim_out, dim_out, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding, bias=bias),
              nn.ReLU()
            )

    def upsample(self, ch_coarse, ch_fine):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ch_coarse, ch_fine, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        conv1_out = self.down1(x)
        conv2_out = self.down2(self.max_pool(conv1_out))
        conv3_out = self.down3(self.max_pool(conv2_out))
        conv4_out = self.down4(self.max_pool(conv3_out))
        conv5_out = self.down5(self.max_pool(conv4_out))
        conv6_out = self.down6(self.max_pool(conv5_out))
        conv7_out = self.down7(self.max_pool(conv6_out))

        out = self.center(self.max_pool(conv7_out))
        #out = self.center_res(out)

        out = self.up7(cat((self.trans7(out), conv7_out), 1))
        out = self.up6(cat((self.trans6(out), conv6_out), 1))
        out = self.up5(cat((self.trans5(out), conv5_out), 1))
        out = self.up4(cat((self.trans4(out), conv4_out), 1))
        out = self.up3(cat((self.trans3(out), conv3_out), 1))
        out = self.up2(cat((self.trans2(out), conv2_out), 1))
        out = self.up1(cat((self.trans1(out), conv1_out), 1))

        out = self.conv_last(out)

        return out
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Answer (score 5):

`pyinstaller` is kind of cheated `.exe`. It does not compile the script, but bundles what's needed (including python interpreter) into one (or many) files.

To really be Python agnostic you should convert your model using `torchscript` (read about it [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html)). You will be able to run your module using C++ `libtorch` without Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:
* convert your model and your params to onnx
* use onnx which has just 14mb (pip install onnx)

See:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/super_resolution_with_caffe2.html