# PyInstaller Error: Python Script unable to run

Tags: python, cmd, pyinstaller

Hello so I have made I python script but now I want to make it into an .exe or .bat. 
I have tried using pyinstaller using the command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile Pythonscript.py
```

and it works but when I try to run it I get a popup message saying

> Error Python Script unable to run.

I have no idea how to fix this.

And here's my script

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

time.sleep(2)

keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
keyboard.press('r')

time.sleep(2)

keyboard.release('r')
keyboard.release(Key.cmd)
keyboard.release(Key.cmd)

time.sleep(2)

keyboard.type('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ')

time.sleep(2)

keyboard.press(Key.enter)

time.sleep(2)

keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Answer (score 1):

Long ago I found this template somewhere, which might help:

```
@echo off
rem = """
rem Do any custom setup like setting environment variables etc if required here ...

python -x "%~f0" %*
goto endofPython """

# Your python code goes here ..

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello World from Python")

rem = """
:endofPython """
```

Comment: Should i type that in notepad or python? And what should the extension be?

Comment: It's (sort-of) a Windows batch file, so you should use a text editor like Notepad.