# Can we create an application using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I wrote a code and  automated one website where I fill the input fields automatically and click submit...Now I want that code to make an application. So that I can fill the fields of whatever content I need through that application. Can I do that, I mean make an application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool called [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) in order to convert a Python selenium script into a standalone executable file.

It's simple to get started:

```bash
pip install -U pyinstaller

pyinstaller YOUR_PROGRAM.py
```

"Your bundled application should now be available in the `dist` folder."

I've used this tool a few times to convert `tkinter` apps (that run Selenium scripts) into standalone executables.

Comment: And then will the app be standalone executable? I mean will it just run successfully on other computer or we need to install some selenium stuff to be able to run that app?

Comment: Depending on the version of Selenium, it should automatically download the chromedriver version that it needs at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the programming language, it is possible to convert your code into a standalone installer.

If you used Python, there's a good explanation available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44433442/7964299).
For Java, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147233/7964299).