# How to transform a file .py to .exe

Tags: python, exe

I read the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python?newreg=9468a98293824ff298364a1be4ec5266) (and others) ,
but I still cannot solve my problem.

I have already created the `file .exe`.
But the program is not behaving as it should.
The basic idea of the program is to read a file (.csv) and then it should give two output other .csv and a .docx. My Python program does that. But the .exe doesn't.
I have the csv where the .exe is, but still is not working :/ the .exe executes but doesn't give me the desired output. Any ideas?
I have tried a lot of different things.

This is one part of the code that doesn't seem to be working in the .exe:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('sales_mejorado.xlsx') as writer:

df_sales.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sales.xlsx")
```

I imported these libraries:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import re 
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
```

Maybe this part it in't working...
(when I call the csv files)

```
df_sales = pd.read_csv('./Sales.csv', sep=',', encoding='latin-1')
```

Thanks in advance. I really need help in this.
Edit: I try too the auto-py-to-exe, and it didn't help :(

Comment: Ummm like what exactly is not working can you read the error in the .exe console because if you can read the error it will be easy to debug the program also how did to convert to .exe like what code you put in cmd to convert it please mention that also

Comment: "doesn't give me the desired output". Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using:

```
auto-py-to-exe
```

It has one directory option which will put all dependencies in one folder :)

Comment: I try that too in first try but Somehow it didn't work either, thanks anyway :)

Comment: you can check this: https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi