# Fatal python error: init_fs_coding when opening python to .exe converted file

Tags: python, pygame, executable

I tried to make my game into a .exe file using this tutorial: [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)
but when i open it it gives an error: fatal python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the python codec of the filesystem encoding Python runtime state: core initialised

The code has No errors, it has a lot of weak warnings though. Also in the code i import images, music, sounds, librarys, python files and text files.

Pycharm shows the error: cx_Freeze not found in the setup.py file made from the [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python) tutorial. I have installed cx_Freeze and idna using pip. Also i can convert other files to a working .exe file, but this one doesn't work.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: We shouldn't have to read all of that code. please take a look at [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

```
import cx_Freeze
from cx_Freeze import * 

setup (
    name = "File name",
    options = {'build_exe':{'packages': ['pygame']}},
    executables = [
        Executable(
            "filename.py",

        )

    ]

)
```

This should be enough to convert it but if you want you can look up a more detailed syntax with more commands.

Save that as `Setup.py` or anything that you want.

Then create another file and type the following

```
py Setup.py build
```

save this as `build.bat`. Make sure you save it as .bat file. Then open up the build file that is created and your exe file will be ready in a few mins.
Please follow this and make sure you have cx_freeze installed

Comment: When i do this and open the executable file is says: pygame.error: couldn't open person.png

Comment: @Tommyvansante Did you put all your pictures and files in the same folder as the exe? Because I have tested this with a decently large project with loads of pictures and imports/libraries.

Comment: I did this, Now it works on a computer with python installed, but on a other computer it doesn't.

Comment: @Tommy van sante It will work, make sure to put all your dependencies in the same folder. I hope you listed all your imports in packages while creating the exe(Setup.py). If it still doesn't work please tell me in detail what's happening.