# Package a Django application as a desktop application

Tags: django, desktop-application

We are considering using Django for an application which can be seen mostly as a desktop application.  That is, it is not to be installed on our servers, but **directly on our customer's laptops** (but still accessed through their browser on localhost.)

Whilst it is OK to require Python to be installed, it is not to require to install Django, or other dependencies.

It would probably run using the internal `runserver`.  And most likely not use SQL (or only SQLite if necessary.)

Is it possible to "package" the application with Django and all dependencies?  **What are the options here?**  Ideally, the install guide would read:

- install Python, if not done yet
- download and unzip our application archive
- go to that dir and execute `python3 manage.py runserver`

Note I: The goal is NOT to package a publicly available website as an app.

Note II: The only related questions I have found are several years old (10 and 7 years old resp.)

Note III: The customers use Linux, Mac and Windows.

Comment: [convert a .py to .exe for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Comment: Thank you. But I forgot to mention that the target is Windows, Mac and Linux. I update the question...