# Compile python file to executable

Tags: python, windows

I'm looking for a compiler to compile '.py' file to a single '.exe' file.

I've try already **auto-py-to-exe** but I'm not happy with it.

I've tried **PyInstaller**, but one of its dependencies (PyCrypto, which I need) is not working/ maintained anymore and fails to install. https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#encrypting-python-bytecode

I've look also **nuitka** but it doesn't seem possible to set an icon for the exe.

Do you have any compiler recommendations that can obfuscate / encrypt the code to limit the reverse engineering?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue to this, needing to run Python code on machines where Python could not be downloaded.

I used py2exe, and it worked quite well. (https://www.py2exe.org/)

Comment: Thanks, but py2exe seem to be discontinued. the last release is : Oct 21, 2014...

Answer (score 1):

You could try these **steps to convert .py to .exe in Python 3.8**

1. Install [Python 3.8](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
2. Install cx_Freeze, (open your command prompt and type `pip install cx_Freeze`.
3. Install idna, (open your command prompt and type `pip install idna`.
4. Write a `.py` a program named `myfirstprog.py`.
5. Create a new python file named `setup.py` on the current directory of your script.
6. In the `setup.py` file, copy the code below and save it.
7. With shift pressed right click on the same directory, so you are able to open a command prompt window.
8. In the prompt, type `python setup.py build`
9. If your script is error-free, then there will be no problem with creating applications.
10. Check the newly created folder `build`. It has another folder in it. Within that folder, you can find your application. Run it. Make yourself happy.

See the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44433442/10250028).