# Is there an alternative to pyinstaller for python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

Since pyinstaller is not available for python 3.8, is there any alternative to convert a .py file into a .exe file?

Edit(for better understanding): I am searching another compiler because pyinstaller is not updated for py 3.8 yet because of the changes in the python bootloader(https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4311)

Comment: http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html#overview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Comment: pyinstaller is working for 3.8 and i am using it

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4311

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternatives for pyinstaller are,

```
py2exe
autopy2exe
cx_freeze
```

py2exe is the same like pyinstaller,
autopy2exe has UI for converting the script to executable,
cx_freeze is platform independent exe creation method.

Comment: would you say cx_freeze is the best of all?

Comment: Sorry i am quite not sure as I haven't used cx_freeze yet @oyeyipowale

Comment: `autopy2exe` is NOT an alternative. Its just GUI to pyinstaller

Answer (score 10):

[PyOxidizer](https://pyoxidizer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyoxidizer_overview.html) is another "fresh" one take in this domain.

[Here](https://pyoxidizer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyoxidizer_comparisons.html) is the comparison of it vs other tools mentioned in the accepted answer.