# .py to .exe with large dependencies

Tags: python, import, dependencies, exe, pyinstaller

I need to convert a python script that contains a large number of large dependencies such as `opencv`, `bs4` and `selenium` into an electable file that can run on a system that dose **not** have python installed. However all the "how to's" on how to convert `.py` to `.exe` never show how to do it with such imports and dependencies (always on a simple 'hello world' program).

When I have tried converting to `.exe` with all these dependencies I always get a missing dependency error.
I have tried with `Pyinstaller` and `cx_Freeze`, `py installer` never worked at all any time I had any dependencies on, however `cx_Freeze` did work for some of my other programs. but not on the `opencv` program.

What is the proper way of converting `.py` to `.exe` with a large amount of dependencies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Comment: You probably know why you can't do it like this but the obvious solution would be an installer for your program that also installs Python (and possibly other dependencies) if needed.

Comment: but even on my system it reports that there are missing dependencies.

Comment: @Meysam so yes that did help to a small extent.  after wading my way through all the errors i got cx_Freeze to work on one of my other high dependency programs, however it was still having problems with my opencv program, i couldn't tell you if it was the dependencies causing the problem because the command terminal only opened for a split second and crashed. however the script works fine?