# Can I compile Python CLI program to exe and run it?

Tags: python, user-interface, compilation, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Basically, I am new to Python and I have made a program that spams a word again and again. I have made a GUI version of it and compiled it to .exe with PyInstaller but I also want to compile the non-GUI version of it to run on every Windows 10 like the GUI version. I know that as my non-GUI version has no GUI so therefore it will run in CMD but is it possible? Can I compile the non-GUI version to .exe and run it on any Windows 10 like the GUI version? If yes, How?

BTW, I have tried to compile the non-GUI version to .exe from PyInstaller and it did compiled it for me but it does not run and throws an error

> Failed to execute the script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's already quite a few topics around this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python
might do the trick for you

Comment: In both of these questions, I cannot find my answer. I am asking that can I run a python script that has no GUI code (runs in the console) and turn it into some kind of compiled file that also runs in the console but without can run without Python installed in the machine. Whenever I compile a py file to .exe with PyInstaller which has no GUI, it compiles it but the .exe cannot run, It says "Script cannot run" or something like that. Is it a problem with my script or PyInstaller? and what?