# Can i compile python file with its audio file so that no one can see its code?

Tags: python

```
import shutil
import time
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('1.mp3')
mixer.music.play()

cols, rows =shutil.get_terminal_size()
print (("YOU SHOULD NOT OPEN THIS FILE").center(cols))
print (("SLEEP PEACEFULLY").center(cols))
time.sleep(3)

os.system("shutdown /h")

input ()
```

This is my code which actually turns the client computer in hibernate mode, with an amazing horror sound. So I want to complie the code so that no one can open the source code and the music.

i have tried to make exe and pyc of this code but it need the music file separately . it is not combined in one file .
To make exe i have used cmd (pyinstaller --onefile {filename})
and to make pyc i have used python itself (py_compile.compile({filename})

Comment: please, can you edit the post adding what you have tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Comment: @Vlad I have tried it but it doesn't cure my problem.

Comment: @Giuppox I have edited it .

Answer (score 1):

You can add your audio files into binary file generated by `pyinstaller` by using `spec` file to config `pyinstaller`

For example:

```
...
a = Analysis(['Main.py'],
             pathex=['F:\\My\\Python\\Projects\\Demo'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
# Put all your audio files into folder ./audios
a.datas += Tree('./audios', 'audios')
...
```

Your project structure should same as bellow:

```
.\Demo\
    Main.py
    audios\
        audio1.mp3
        audio2.mp3
```

Refer [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) for more detail.