# How to convert .py file to .exe hiding the console (based on another stackoverflow's post)

Tags: python

I tried several ways to convert a `.py` file to a `.exe`, but it always gave me the same problem, namely that the `.exe` file didn’t work. I found a solution thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python), but it is not specified how to hide the console. Could someone check the post and tell me how to do it?

EDIT:

After searching I found out a solution for my problem:

```
import cx_Freeze

exe = [cx_Freeze.Executable("game.py", base = "Win32GUI")] # "Win32GUI" -> no console

packages = ["os", "time", "random", "io", "pygame", "base64", "paho.mqtt"]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "ForzaQuattro",
    version = "1.0",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages": packages,  
        "include_files": []}},
    executables = exe
)
```

I used cx_Freeze with the param `base="Win32GUI"`, this will hide the console of the exe file.

After that you will just replace `game.py` with the name of your python script, replace `packages` with the package that you need, save that file as `setup.py` and run by command prompt `python setup.py build`.

That will genarate a directory with all what you need.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOIJIk_maO4

Comment: or use this https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Comment: @matiiss I tried pyinstaller but this doesn't work. My exe file doesn't open at all.

Comment: did You try auto py to exe?

Comment: @matiiss yes, it is the same thing. Auto-py-to-exe uses pyinstaller.

Comment: I know but I don't understand why it won't open

Comment: and what do You mean it doesn't open at all, it had to at least show an error message or sth. also is Your program text based (on console?)

Comment: @matiiss my program has a GUI made with pygame, the .py file work properly, instead the exe file once executed does not open. If i use the method in the post linked before, this works, but with the console

Comment: I have no idea of how to hide the console in that case, except if You use shortcuts they have the option to minimize the console or sth like that

Comment: @matiiss thanks anyway :)

Comment: If `pyinstaller` "doesn't work" I recommend reading the very helpful section of the documentation titled "When things go wrong".

Comment: @BoarGules thank you, btw I found out a solution without using pyinstaller, I editet the post with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
pyinstaller -w [PathToYourFile]
```

The -w option hides the console.

Comment: I tried using pyistaller but this doesn't work, btw i found out a solution