# How to get exe from Python file; ModuleNotFound error

Tags: python, pygame, auto-py-to-exe

I want to transform a Python script to an .exe to share it with friends. I've tried with [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/), but here is what I get when I open it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I saw somewhere that I had to indicate in auto-py-to-exe's interface the module name here:

[image: Hidden Importation PyGame]

But I still get the same error.

Comment: tried `--onefile` option?

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ yes tried but not working as well

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced this before where I export `.py` into `.exe` with `--onedir` setup. Here are the solutions that I might suggest (and works for me)

**1. Export as `--onefile`**

[auto-py-to-exe screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikmQN.png)

Exporting using `--onefile` creates only a single .exe file instead of having a folder contain hundreds of other supporting files (is that term exist? IDK). but the drawback is the file will be painstakingly slow to load up.

but if you export it as `--onefile` but still doesn't work,

**2. Ensure the `pygame` is in the same directory as your `.exe` file**

Apparently your .exe app is looking for the `pygame` module but failed. Try putting it in the same directory as your source code

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to [convert a python file(`.py`) to an executable(`.exe`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python) -:

- [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/)
- [auto-py-to-exe](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe)

Also, as mentioned in the comments by @Nanthakumar JJ and by @Amar Haiqal in his answer, make sure the `--onefile` option is checked while using auto-py-to-exe for conversion. Further, pygame module has to be present within the directory of the main file that is being compiled, as it will look for pygame and raise a [`ModuleNotFoundError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ModuleNotFoundError), if the module is not found, being an `.exe` it will not look for the module on [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

[image: --onefile option in auto-py-to-exe]