# Start a .py with an .exe

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe

I have a GUI.py that starts another .py which I made in Jupyter Notebook and it works. But now I made my GUI.py to an .exe and it doesn‘t start my .py because subprocess.Popen can‘t find it.

I did use resource_path function but it didn‘t help. Does anyone has any idea how to find the .py differently or any other tipps. It‘s my first time making an .exe[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h46bd.png)

Comment: Maybe you should include a simple example. Why are you using subprocess?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - How to create a [mre]

Comment: Check out [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python) for advice.